# JQTOUCH animation effect not working on separate pages

Tags: jquery, jsp, mobile, jqtouch

I want to use the jqtouch animation effects.My scenario is suppose I am having two html pages named as first.html and second.html. First.html has a anchor tag which references to the second.html. And second.html also has a anchor tag which references to first.html.With this href I am also passing query parameters.I want to have the animation effects between this pages.

I am unable to give the effects using jqtouch as the sample application is showing the effects in the same page itself.Please provide some help regarding this effects. what changes should I make in the script and provide sample code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestion provided by addydmasi on [JQTouch Animations Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/Animations)? Pasting the relevant comment below for easy reference:

```
To those who want to animate between two separate web pages, try this in your <body>:

<div id="main"><ul><li><a href="#page1" class="slide">Go to another page</a></li></ul></div>
<div id="page1"><iframe src="http://google.com">Error</iframe></div>
Replace the src with the file name of the second page and also "page1" with any other name. Then add this to your <head>:

<style type="text/css">div>iframe{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;border-width:0;}</style>
```

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer ,I have tried a number of ways , but iframe is remaining so I will give this one a try.